# Get text from specific control on another window

Tags: c#, interop

I am trying very hard to figure out how to get text from a control in another applications window.  In short, I am trying to automate the process of checking if another application is running, then, if it is found, getting the text from what I believe is one of the first controls in the window.

There does not appear to be any child windows in the application.  I can't seem to find any child controls using Spy++.

I can get the title of the window, and a handle to the application using

```
 IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "Zuercher Mobile");
```

I can't seem to find a way to iterate through child controls and get their text.  Examples typically show how to get text out of Notepad, but you know the name of the control is "EDIT". I don't know the name of the control that has the text I am trying to retrieve.

As an example I have tried

```
   private void GetAllText(IntPtr handle)
        {

            IntPtr Handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
            IntPtr ChildHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            int NumText = (int)SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)50, Handle);


            // Loop through all the textboxes that are children of Hwnd.
            int childNo = 0;
            while ((ChildHandle = FindWindowEx(handle, ChildHandle, "Zuercher Mobile", "")) != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr Hndl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200);

                NumText = (int)SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)200, Hndl);
                Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl);
                textBox1.Text += "(Child Number " + childNo + ") " + Text + Environment.NewLine;
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Hndl);

                childNo++;
            }
        }
```

Which only shows 0 child controls.

How can this be done?  I have tried. [Problems getting text from control on another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706185/problems-getting-text-from-control-on-another-window)
and 
[Can't get text from another application (window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008433/cant-get-text-from-another-application-window)

without success.

Comment: If it's a WPF application, you won't find child controls' handles that way, there aren't any to find. You need UI Automation.

Comment: If you're looking for a TextBox, its type is  `ControlType.Edit` (`UIA_EditControlTypeId`), if it's a RichTextBox, its type is `ControlType.document` (`UIA_DocumentControlTypeId`).